# Starbucks® Keurig® pods "ZPCK 44088544" meaning?

Tags: starbucks, keurig, pods

I have some Starbucks® Limited Edition Pumpkin Spice Keurig® pods. They are not labeled for individual sale, but they do have "ZPCK 44088544" stamped on them. What does this mean? Does it tell me when the unit was packaged, roasted, or ground?

[image: Starbucks® Limited Edition Pumpkin Spice Keurig® pod with "ZPCK 44088544"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a [natural key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key) (human readable) form of the ID found in Keurig products' matrix code.

The matrix code decodes to `5000362049` (50 being a constant across products), when in binary share similar numbers to the ZPCK code; their own encoding.

```
ZPCK 44088544
      8...8...     4...?
001101100010000001001001
```

I've found the ZPCK code on products labeled for sale and for non-Starbucks. **It does not tell you dates/times for anything as its unique per thing.**